# How to use ExtJS Framework within Oracle ADF

Tags: javascript, jsf, extjs, oracle-adf

How can i use ExtJs JavaScript library in My ADF web applications.

ExtJS is a powerful and visually stunning JavaScript library that will definitely turn heads.
How can I implement ExtJS in ADF?

Thanks for your helps

Comment: Please, refine your question. What you mean by **using**? You can include any JS file into your page and then use it as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADF provides all the components which are provided by ExtJs as well. Can you state why would you want to use ExtJS? And one can use `<af:resource>` tag to link any Javascript files.